# Python 3.6 Mbox to CSV

Tags: python, csv, email, mbox

I'm trying to write a script that will convert each email element of an `.mbox` file into a `.csv` file. I specifically need the following elements, but if there was a way to "write for each element," that'd be preferred:

To, From, CC'd, BCC'd, Date, Subject, Body

I found a script online that looks to be the start of what I need, and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.html#module-email) about the email module, but I can't find any specifics on how to

1. identify the different attribute options (`to`, `from`, `cc`'d, etc.)
2. how to write them as unique cell values in a `.csv`.

Here is sample code I found:

```
import mailbox
import csv

writer = csv.writer(open("clean_mail_B.csv", "wb"))
for message in mailbox.mbox('Saks.mbox'):
    writer.writerow([message['to'], message['from'], message['date']])
```

Comment: Add `print(message)` inside your loop and you would then see which items are available.

Comment: That's brilliant. I've been trying to figure out how to do something that simple. I'm new to python, so forgive the ignorance, haha. Will try asap

Comment: @MartinEvans - so I did that, and it certainly printed the message, but it was very scrambled. It didn't really list the properties available so much as the actual content of the file. Not sure if that's what you had in mind, but it was still a bit foreign to me.

Comment: It will show you all the information that is available in the form of a Python dictionary. i.e. it works by associating a word (or key) to a definition (or value). To just see which keys are available e.g. `to` or `from`, use `print(message.keys())`

Comment: Thank you @MartinEvans . That makes perfect sense. I will try that out.

Comment: Hey @MartinEvans , I've been playing around with the file, and the .csv reader, and it turns out there are a lot of key/value pairs. Do you know of a way to have it take each message and break it up into different values? The keys should be the header and the values should be all the values separated by commas in the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do that you would first need to determine the complete list of possible keys present in all mailbox items. Then you can use that to write the CSV header.

Next you need to get all the key value pairs from each message using `.items()`. This can then be converted back into a dictionary and written to your CSV file.

The `mailbox` library unfortunately does not directly expose the message dictionary otherwise it would have been possible to write this directly.

```
import mailbox
import csv

mbox_file = 'sample.mbox'

with open('clean_mail_B.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    # Create a column for the first 30 message payload sections
    fieldnames = {f'Part{part:02}' for part in range(1, 31)}

    for message in mailbox.mbox(mbox_file):
        fieldnames.update(message.keys())

    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=sorted(fieldnames), restval='', extrasaction='ignore')
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for message in mailbox.mbox(mbox_file):
        items = dict(message.items())

        for part, payload in enumerate(message.get_payload(), start=1):
            items[f'Part{part:02}'] = payload

        csv_output.writerow(items)
```

A `DictWriter` is used rather than a standard CSV writer. This would then cope better for when certain message do not contain all possible header values.

The message payload can be in multiple parts, these are added as separate column headers e.g. `Part01`, `Part02`. Normally there should be 1 or 2 but your sample mbox contained one with a strange signature containing 25?

If the `mbox` contains more payload entries for a message (i.e. >30), these are ignored using `extrasaction='ignore'`. An alternative approach would be to combine all payloads into a single column.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this. I got sidelined at work by another project, but this is back on my plate. This works perfectly with one exception. Apparently, none of the keys correspond to the actual message. I can see the message in the .mbox file reading it manually, but I need it to be one of the .csv file's columns. Any idea on that?

Comment: Can you use something like pastebin to paste a link to a sample mbox file? I could then take a look at it.

Comment: I'm looking for one now. I have a few, but they have work information in the details so I'd rather find something more neutral.

Comment: This might do the trick: https://github.com/qsnake/git/blob/master/t/t5100/sample.mbox

Comment: You can use `get_payload()` to get the message content and then add that as another key to the dictionary to be written. I have updated the script to show how that can be done.

Comment: So, when I run that, the Message field populates this:

[<email.message.Message object at 0x0000019B4B9BB748>, <email.message.Message object at 0x0000019B4B9ADC88>]

Comment: They mbox you are testing on might have multi part messages. It would need a for loop to convert each part.

Comment: OK, I found another post that had a loop, but it converts the message into a text, not into a .csv. I think I can adapt it, but if you have any more time to help. I could post the code? I appreciate everything so far, so I understand if this is taking up too much time.

Comment: Could you give me a link to a suitable mbox file?

Comment: I can leave this up for a while. It has personal information so please let me know once you have it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14O_McULhYRuSDtERBoX8Jpf3u1azH5zD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I downloaded it. Most messages do contain multiple parts. One has 25. Each part could be given its own CSV column. I will post an update for you that does this.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That work pretty well. Out of the 11 emails in the mbox, part 1 seems to be all that's necessary, but there are 30 "part" columns. Also, 1 of the 11 emails has a single letter in each part, spelling out "testing email signature." Minor issues, really. If you run the code on the .mbox I shared you should see it. I'll have to test the script with a larger .mbox, but I think this is like 90-95% of what I need.

Comment: What is the `fieldnames = {'Part{:02}'.format(part) for part in range(1, 31)}` about? Is there anyway to make that dynamic? I was getting an error cause mine went up to about 900, so I changed it and got an error because I guess another line or something went up to 1700? I don't even know what it is, but yeah it'd be great if it were dynamic

Comment: The library returns payloads in the message separately, if you don't need to access these individually then one solution would be to combine them into a single (possibly huge) entry. It is not possible to know the maximum number of payloads used without parsing everything first (so the correct header could be determined)

Comment: Other payloads can be ignored by adding the option `extrasaction='ignore'`

Comment: Awesome script. Thanks!