# I need to parse through an mbox file and count the return count of emails grouped by dates

Tags: python, pandas

I couldnt find any code online to do this, any help would be great! I did find the mailbox library but I am not sure how to extract the date from there.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

To be able to group values, you need to first convert your data into a tabular format. Refer to this [answer script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50943700/2111379) in order to convert an MBOX file to CSV or TSV file.

Then you can read the CSV and group by using this sample code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('exported.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", errors='coerce', utc=True)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date
grouped_df = df.groupby('Date')['Date'].count().reset_index(name="Count")
```

Sample Output of grouped_df data frame. I have used this sample [mbox file](https://github.com/qsnake/git/blob/master/t/t5100/sample.mbox).

[image]